# Export Crystal Reports to PDF via .NET 6 web application

Tags: asp.net-core, crystal-reports, .net-6.0

I have been building a .NET 6 web application for a customer and now I need to print Crystal Reports from the app.

Can anyone put me in the right direction since from what I found, CR is not compatible with .NET 6.... but changing to .NET Framework is not an option.

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to this [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/480438/asp-net-core-crystal-reports-integration).

Answer (score 0):

Crystal for VS does not support .NET Core because the Crystal runtime has dependencies on COM components.

You could create the Crystal portion of your app in .NET 4.8 and call that app from your .NET core app.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that?

My idea would be to create a .NET Framework library that handles the Crystal report part and then returns a stream.

But I keep having issues with components that won't load.

Any examples would be appreciated